# Ubuntu Password help

Tags: wubi, password

I installed Ubuntu using wubi it asked me to enter a password for my account . I entered the same password twice . When I booted ubuntu it asked for my username I entered it then it asked  for my password I entered the correct password but It says that my pass word is incorrect , I  have  installed ubuntu twice and the same problem occurs again . Pleas help.

Comment: Check the keyboard layout. Perhaps you've installed in a language other than the one that is now used.

Comment: Open TTY1 with Ctrl-Alt-F1 and try a login there. Then update your question with the new findings